# How to get not 20 elements from the server, but for example 5? (redux toolkit rtk query)

Tags: toolkit, rtk-query

```
export const rickandmortyApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'rickandmorty/api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        searchCharacter: builder.query<ServerResponse, any>({
            query: (page = 1) =>  `character?page=${page}`
        }),
    }),
})

export const {useSearchCharacterQuery} = rickandmortyApi
```

[1][Server responce]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR0hr.png

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#rest:

`character?page=${page}&count=5`